# Correct way to tag x509 certificate with identity of user that created it?

Tags: certificate, pki

I have a Windows service that processes Certificate Signing Requests to make Certificates. It also makes self signed certificates (Certificate Authorities) on request by Windows users. In either case, I want to put the user account name (the NT Account string like 'domain\user') from the user who made the request to make the certificate in the finished certificate so that it is straightforward to track who created what.

Where is the best place to stick a user account string in a certificate? The first thing that came to mind is a custom extension. Does that make the most sense? Or perhaps an alternate field in the subject? I do not know if this is at all a common practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't committed to using the NT Account format, you could consider the `emailAddress` attribute in the certificate `subjectName`.  Simply change `Test\Bloggs` to `bloggs@test`.

There is also the `pseudonym` attribute that could be used.  However, while OpenSSL displays this attribute's name correctly, Windows shows it as `2.5.4.65` which may not be what you want.

In theory, the `subjectAltName` extension could also be used to store this.  There is a `otherName` field, that could be used.  However, OpenSSL displays a certificate as follows:

```
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
            DNS:test.example.org, othername:<unsupported>
```

While Windows displays:

```
DNS Name=test.example.org
Other Name:
     1.3.6.1.4.1.1=0c 0b 54 45 53 54 5c 42 6c 6f 67 67 73
```

Obviously, neither are any good to you.

Therefore, be pragmatic - either use the `pseudonym` and live with the way Windows displays it, or be even more pragmatic and hijack the OrgnaizationalUnitName (OU) attribute and use that.  You can have multiple OUs therefore there wouldn't be a need to sacrifice any current OUs you may have.  Digicert, Microsoft and Verisign (and no doubt, others) use the OU as an additional text field without any harm. It may not be 100% standard compliant, but it works.

If you do go down the latter route and you are using name constraints, make sure that this additional OU is first in the list when creating your signing request.  That is, it doesn't break the order of the name constraint.